# Rejecting zero values when creating a list of minimum values. (Python Field Calc)

Tags: python, arcgis, minimum

I'm trying to create a list of minimum values from four columns of values. Below is the statement I have used.

```
min ([!Depth!, !Depth_1!, !Depth_12!, !Depth_1_13!])
```

The problem I'm having is that some of the fields under these columns contain zeros. I need it to return the next lowest value from the columns that is greater than zero.

I have an attribute table for a shapefile from an ArcGIS document. It has 10 columns. ID, Shape, Buffer ID (x4), Depth (x4).

I need to add an additional column to this data which represents the minimum number from the 4 depth columns. Many of the cells in this column are equal to zero. I need the new column to take the minimum value from the four depth columns but ignore the zero values and take the next lowest value.

A screen shot of what I am working from:

[image]

Comment: That's... not Python.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know much about code. I'm using ArcGIS software and in the field calculator I use to input the above statement. Parser: Python is selected.

Comment: You should figure out what language you need to use.

Comment: Yeah in Arcgis they use `!x!` to refer to Python and differentiate from `[x]` that would refer to Visual Basic. In the calc filed you will need to create a function to do the min for you.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, it's the function that I need advice on. What I've tried returns '0' as a minimum.

Comment: Can you post some fields of the shp table. What are you getting and what do you want.

Comment: I have a list of polygon attributes. The fields I'm interested in are depth. The depth fields are:

Comment: Depth = 15, the rest of the fields shown in the original question are zero. When I run the statement I have written, it returns the minimum value as zero when I would need it to be 15 in this case

Comment: I can't send a screenshot because I've just joined.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include all the new information. You dont need to include all the rows but just a couple to provide enough context.

Comment: @DanielJimenez I have updated the original question. If there is specific info you require let me know.

Thanks

Comment: @Temp upload an image to imgur (or the like) and post a link to it as a comment.  Someone will then be able to inline it in the question itself.

Comment: @MichaelT

[Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/nlMw18t.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function that does it for you. I added a pic so you can follow the steps. Just change the input names to your column names.

```
def my_min(d1,d2,d3,d4):       
    lst = [d1,d2,d3,d4]        
    return min([x for x in lst if x !=0])
```

[image]

Comment: @Temp, Cool, glad i could help. FYI, this would be a more approipate forum for gis questions http://gis.stackexchange.com